# Flash, cant reach movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, movieclip, nested

I am working on a flash step-by-step guide. and i have a problem.

There are 3 layers,
1 is scripts
2 is invisible button
3 is a cover screen(mc)

, inside cover screen. on its own timeline , it has an animation.

, what im trying to do is ; when i roll over the invisible button , i want the cover screen timeline to play and stop at a certain frame, when rolled out, i want it to play again and get to the beginning.

I used this on my invisible button.

on (rollOver){
    cover.gotoAndPlay("fadein");
}
on (rollOut) {
    cover.gotoAndPlay("fadeout");
}
fadein and fadeout are the frame names inside cover_mc

but id doeswnt work:S

any idea's why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use trace :)

```
on (rollOver){
    trace(cover);
    cover.gotoAndPlay("fadein");
}
```

if nothing traces than there's probably something wrong with your rollOver action.
It must trace [Object MovieClip] (or something like that, i'm not quite sure.. its ages since i did some AS2 development)

if it traces coorect, then you probably have a problem with your frame label.
it also could be that the cover instance is not know from your rollOver function, try _root.cover.gotoAndPlay("fadein");

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the code is on the button and you want the parent timeline to react on roll actions.

so try the following:

```
on (rollOver) {
   _parent.gotoAndPlay('fadein');
}
```

The key thing is the **_parent**, which obviously will address the parent of the button.